# When and how to use [ResponseType(typeof(...))] correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on a project and I have a basic controller with `Get(int id)`, `GetElements()`, `UpdateElement(int id, Element element)`, `AddElement(Element element)` and `DeleteElement(int id)`.
Every method use `[Route]` and `[Get]`... annotations and returns an `IHttpActionResult`.

I am confused about `[ResponseType(typeof(...))]`. What is it for? When and how to use it correctly?

Should I write something like this?
`[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Element>))]` for `GetElements()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `[ResponseType()]` attribute is helpful for creating RESTful Web APIs and also when autogenerating documentation via Swagger / Swashbuckle.

For instance an approach to returning a item based on an id could be written like this

```
public YourClass Get(int id)
{
    var item = repo.GetById(id);
    return item;
}
```

However if that item is not found it will return null, rather than a 404.

So it could be better written as

```
[ResponseType(typeof(YourClass))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var item = repo.GetById(id);
    if (item != null)
    {
        return this.Ok(item);
    }

    return this.NotFound();
}
```

See more uses of this here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing

See also customizing Swashbuckle and how it ResponseType attributes can be used to determine documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-swashbuckle-customize/

Comment: What would you declare in `ResponseType` if the endpoint returns something other than a model...like a streamed file for example.

Comment: @crush That's a good question, to which I don't know the answer. There doesn't appear to be any example of this online

Comment: This should be `IActionResult<YourClass>` and decorated with `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]` and `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]`

Comment: This was correct at the time of writing and applies to MVC not .NET Core. The down vote was unnecessary